# Why is the <u> tag being added to my EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm typing into an `EditText`, and logging it like this:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, Html.toHtml(new SpannableStringBuilder(s)));
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

The LogCat output looks like this:

```
<p dir="ltr"><u>typing stufffff</u></p>
```

I'm not using an EditText subclass, and I'm not setting any custom styles.

What could be causing the `<u>` tag to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That  tag is a underlined tag. The `EditText` must be underlined. This is due to the fact that there are Text Suggestions. If you set the inputType using the TextView.setInputType(int) method, or one in a .xml file, you can get rid of the tag.

Comment: You are correct. The only thing that is worth noting, just for those that aren't aware, is that you can create your own drawable xml to update the look of the line. You can also remove the line with a little code, but it isn't really recommended.

Comment: Yes, it's good to have that line, because if that line is removed, then the user can't even see the `EditText`.

Comment: Good call, you're right about the <u> being there because it's underlined.  However, it seems like the underline is NOT because of that bottom bar, but rather from the text suggestions.  If I set the attribute inputType to textNoSuggestions the actual text is not underlined and the <u> tag goes away.  If you edit your answer to this explanation I'll accept it.